# "Closed Now" or "Now Closed"?

Tags: phrasing

[image: Current copy text indicating library closure.]

[image: Current copy text indicating business hours today.]

Hello all,

We just added a new feature to our site where a status bar auto updates based on the Library hours, so we had to add an alternate state for when it's closed. I'm confused as to how the phrasing should be - as is in the picture, "is closed", or "is now closed" or "is closed now" to clearly convey the message that the closure is temporary and will reopen at a later time.

Comment: "Is currently closed", perhaps? Although "is now closed" seems clear enough.

Comment: @Mick Ideally "is currently closed" would make the most sense but I'm not sure if I'll be able to fit in the characters. Thanks for the suggestion 

Comment: Alternatively, and more usefully to readers, perhaps something like “Opens at 12 AM”. Otherwise, the verb is not needed: “Currently closed” works just fine.

Comment: Wow, a library that opens at midnight? You must have some dedicated early birds!

Comment: "Closed now" is the standard at present for the internet -- cf. google.